# Extension to all dimensions of complex line integral

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, several-complex-variables

Let $\Gamma$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb{C}^d$. Since $\mathbb{C}^d$ can be seen as $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$, one can define the line integral of functions $f:\Gamma\to \mathbb{C}$ using for instance arclength parametrization.

However, when $d=1$, one can use the usual complex line integral of complex analysis instead. Is there a natural extension of this definition when $d \geq 2$ ?

Comment: The most natural extension would have f mapping to $C^d$ rather than $C$.

Comment: Yes, sure. But i'm dealing with functions defined on curves and the arclength definition of integration does not seem adequate.

Comment: The line integral of complex analysis is the integral of a 1-form, so we can immediately generalize to integration of 1-forms along curves, which is defined in any manifold. The line integral of complex analysis is not an arc length integral of a function.

Comment: Unfortunatlely I'm not familiar with 1-form. Is the function f, defined on $\Gamma$, a 1-form ?

Comment: @Chr: no, a function on a curve is not a 1-form. You can read Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds, for a nice introduction to differential forms. But your question does not appear to be a question of research; perhaps this is the wrong website for your question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reference. However, I can assure you that question rose during my research. I am trying to construct an explicit solution to a differential equation and I am conviced I need to integrate (in some sense) a function along a curve. However, the arc length integral does not work and in the case $d=1$ the line integral of complex analysis would work, hence my question.